# Combine Date and Time using DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

How can I combine date and time to generate datetime type in DolphinDB?

For example, combine 2020.01.01 and 01:00:00 as 2020.01.01T01:00:00.

Any suggestions？

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **concatDateTime** function.